# Convert text/bad formatted date to SQL Readable DateTime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, charindex

I have a manually input date that looks something like this:

Wed Dec 21 19:23:32 2016 ,servername.domain.name.com,Random-String-Of-Text-Goes-Here

It's weird, I know, I can't change the way they're doing things. My goal is to get this date into any format that SQL Server sees as a date. Through a disgusting mess of code, I've managed to get it down to:

Dec 21 19:38:12 2016

```
substring(LEFT(FIELDVALUE, CHARINDEX(',', FIELDVALUE) - 1),5,LEN(LEFT(FIELDVALUE, CHARINDEX(',', FIELDVALUE) - 1)))
```

But the problem now is that the time is in between the day and year fields.

It will always be a 3Digit Month, space 2 digit day, space 8 digit time, space 4 digit year.

MON DD HH:MI:SS YYYY

Again, any format that SQL recognizes as a date will work. I'm importing these strings into a second database, and using an Excel macro or something else every time will not work. I imagine another charindex or two and I'll be there, but what I have is already such a mess I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand, your question, your looking to extract the date from the string and reformat it.

```
Declare @String varchar(max)='Wed Dec 21 19:23:32 2016 ,servername.domain.name.com,Random-String-Of-Text-Goes-Here'
Select Try_Convert(datetime,stuff(left(@String,charindex(' ,',@String)),1,4,'') )
```

> **Returns**

```
2016-12-21 19:23:32.000
```

**And with Format(),** you can apply the desired format

```
Declare @String varchar(max)='Wed Dec 21 19:23:32 2016 ,servername.domain.name.com,Random-String-Of-Text-Goes-Here'
Select Format(Try_Convert(datetime,stuff(left(@String,charindex(' ,',@String)),1,4,'') ),'MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy')
```

> **Returns**

```
Dec 21 19:23:32 2016
```

> **EDIT - With a table**

```
Declare @YourTable table (FieldName varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Wed Dec 21 19:23:32 2016 ,servername.domain.name.com,Random-String-Of-Text-Goes-Here'),
('Thu Dec 22 17:05:05 2016 ,servername.domain.name.com,Random-String-Of-Text-Goes-Here-and-here')

Select AsDate    = Try_Convert(datetime,stuff(left(FieldName,charindex(' ,',FieldName)),1,4,'') )
      ,Formatted = Format(Try_Convert(datetime,stuff(left(FieldName,charindex(' ,',FieldName)),1,4,'') ),'MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy')
 From @YourTable
```

Returns

```
AsDate                     Formatted
2016-12-21 19:23:32.000    Dec 21 19:23:32 2016
2016-12-22 17:05:05.000    Dec 22 17:05:05 2016
```

Comment: This works when declaring the string, but when I throw it into my query, everything comes back null. If I run it without the rest of my query, and just as a standalone select I get Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Yes, I replaced it with FIELDVALUE which is the name of the field.

Comment: @Nick Any nulls in your data or strings which don't conform?

Comment: No problem, thank you for helping! There are nulls in the data, and doing the charindex leaves some trailing " in a few fields. I have been combating this by adding in REPLACE(FIELDVALUE, '"','') and specifying where fieldvalue is not null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131290/discussion-between-nick-and-john-cappelletti).